# Get the callback of Paypal payment in PHP

Tags: php, paypal

I have this code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $paypal_url; ?>" method="post" name="frmPayPal1">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<?php echo $paypal_id; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Suscripcion 1 Mes">
    <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="{{ Auth::User()->id }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="handling" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://betea.cf/cancel">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://betea.cf/success">
    <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="<?php echo $random ?>">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/es_ES/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - La manera mas segura de comprar online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/es_ES/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <input name="notify_url" value="http://betea.cf/success" type="hidden">
</form>
```

And in the success, this:

```
    $id = $_POST['userid'];
    $fecha = Carbon::now()->addMonths(1);
    User::where('id', $id)
        ->update(['role' => 'premium', 'expire' => $fecha]);
```

But when PayPal go to the success, says that `userid` does not exist. How can I pass a custom variable to the payment and get it in the success?

Comment: It is really the way to go, check online for tutorial on Paypal IPN, and then in your paypal form you'll be able to add a input tha will have the name "custom" where you can add custom values. Then, you'll tell paypal in the IPN (Instant Payment Notification) to look for a php file. In this PHP file, you'll be able to access the whole post request done to paypal with additionnal field generated by paypal

Answer (score 1):

IPN is indeed the best way to update your system after transactions take place, but your biggest problem here is that you can't just add your own field names to the form.  "userid" means nothing to the PayPal system, so it would simply be ignored.

They provide a single custom field that is literally called custom.  Within that field you can include any value you want up to 256 characters, so you could pass your ID there, and then it would come back $_POST['custom'].

Again, though, it really is better to use IPN for post transaction processing.